# JavaScript browser conditional execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fallback

I'm using a JS library called [fallback.js](http://fallback.io/).
It loads all it's `<link>`'s at the very bottom of the `<head>` tag. My issue is that I need to load some stylesheets LAST, but they need IE conditional comments (fallback does not natively support this). The only thing I can think of is to do something like `if < IE 8 then>` in JS but I have no idea how to do that, let alone in this context.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do u want to detect ie8?

Comment: Speciffically `[if lte IE 8]` and `[if gt IE 8]`

Comment: why don't you just wrap the CSS links inside IE conditional tags (as you wrote in the comment)? You don't need JavaScript for this. > http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: The fallback.js library always adds everything last in the head tag. If I just added my conditional links in HTML they'd load first. They need to load after another particular stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$.browser.msie` to check for IE8 or less

```
if($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version)&lt;8){//do other stuffreturn;}
```

Comment: Will try this later on today